# Submit zipcode as session value in form and show thank you in same modal popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal, modal-popup

I want to show bootstrap modal popup asking only once per visitor for postal/zip code while we open the web page. On submission, postal/zip code should be store in session variable and a thank you  message should be displayed in same modal popup.

The parent page should refresh when the modal popup is closed.

Please help me.

For hint, please find below link. it show modal popup once per visitor but not submission.

http://www.jqueryscript.net/lightbox/jQuery-Plugin-To-Show-A-Popup-Only-Once-Per-Visitor-First-Visit-Popup.html